# pandas dataframe compare few columns for equality

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes with 5 columns each. The values of the first 4 columns are supposed to be same in both dataframes. How do i compare the two dataframes first 4 columns for equality?

df1 columns ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'count']
df2 columns ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'count']

Comment: The answer depends on the data, of which you've given none.

Answer (score 1):

> df1.csv

```
a,b,c,d,count
1,2,3,4,10
1,2,3,4,11
1,2,5,4,12
1,2,3,4,13
```

> df2.csv

```
a,b,c,d,count
1,2,3,4,20
1,2,3,4,21
1,2,5,4,22
1,2,3,4,23
```

> test.py

```
#!/bin/python

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

print((df1[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] == df2[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]).all().all())
# => True
```